# Как скачать удаленный файл, который лежит в папке под паролем (php)

Tags: php

Есть файл на удаленном сервере:
Но папка **folder** запаролена через .htaccess и .passwd. Логин и пароль известен.
Как с помощью пхп авторизоваться чтобы делать дальнейшие манипуляции?

```
$filePatch = 'https://www.site/folder/file.xml';
$xml_reader = new XMLReader;
$xml_reader->open($filePatch);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логин и пароль можно передать через URL:

```
https://логин:пароль@example.com/path
```

Comment: @DGDays **не стоит** проверять ответы, если отсутствуют знания, необходимые для понимания того что написано в ответе.

Comment: @DGDays аргументируйте. если мой ответ действительно не является ответом, то я с радостью сам же его и удалю.

Comment: Признаю свою ошибку. Показалось, что это ответ-ссылка, потому и пометил ответ)

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Да я вкурсе, нажал, но - http://joxi.ru/D2PVb3lhqy9D5r